# Is there the concept of uploading a Deployment without causing pods to start?

Tags: kubernetes

(I am (all things considered) a Kubernetes rookie.)

I know that `kubectl create -f myDeployment.yaml` will send my deployment specification off to the cluster to be reified, and if it says to start three replicas of its contained pod template then Kubernetes will set about starting up three pods.

I wonder: is there a Kubernetes concept or practice of somehow uploading the deployment for reference later and then "activating" it later?  Perhaps by, say, changing `replicas` from zero to some positive number?  If this is not a meaningful question, or this isn't the Right Way To Think About Things, I'd appreciate pointers as well.

Comment: What you're doing will work as intended and does not seem to be against The Way Of Kubernetes. But could you describe your use-case in more detail? Why would you not create a deployment with replicas=3 directly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm coming at this from the standpoint of first reifying a deployment and then "activating" it.  The idea would be: create a deployment, then proof it, then activate it very simply.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you idea would work well with Kubernetes. Firstly, there so no way of "pausing" a Deployment or any other ReplicationController or ReplicaSet, besides setting the `replicas` to `0`, as you mentioned.

The next issue is, that the YAML you would get from the apiserver isn't the same as you created. The controller manager adds some annotations, default values and statuses. So it would be hard to verify the Deployment that way.

IMO a better way to verify Deployments is to add them to a version control system and peer-review the YAML files. Then you can create or update is on the apiserver with `kubectl apply -f myDeployment.yaml`. If the Deployment is wrong in term of syntax, then `kubectl` will complain about it and you could patch the Deployment accordingly. This also simplifies the update procedure of Deployments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  So am I correct in assuming that the general mindset here is that `kubectl apply`/`kubectl create` doesn't just save things to storage, but also starts things running (and billing :-))?  Unlike, say, Docker, where there are (in general) commands to create and then commands to "start" things?

Answer (score 0):

Deployment can be paused, please refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#pausing-and-resuming-a-deployment , or see information with `kubectl rollout pause -h`.

You can adjust replicas of a paused deployment, but changes on pod template will not trigger a rollout. If the deployment is paused in the middle of a rollout, then it will not continue until you resume it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  But when a deployment is `create`d, it immediately begins "running", right?  That is, Kubernetes _immediately_ begins attempting to bring the state of the system to the deployment state specification?